# Multiple Criteria in Mapbox Expressions

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-studio

I am trying to determine method of stying across a data range using 'get' expression and multiple criteria in Mapbox Studio using Mapbox Expressions.  In the example below I want to style a marker matching symbol = 'Restaurant' AND title = 'Social Brewery and Kitchen'. Is this possible?

```
[
  "match",
  ["get", "title", 'Social Kitchen and Brewery'],
  ["get", "marker-symbol", 'Restaurant'],
  "#f9a951",
  "#000000" //fallback
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try concatenating the values:

```
["match",
  ["concat",
    ["get", "title"],
    ["get", "marker-symbol"],
  ],
  "Social Kitchen and BreweryRestaurant",
  "#f9a951",
  "#000000" //fallback
]
```

You may want to add a separaror with a second nested `concat` (or maybe expect a *space* character between values in the first place, I haven't tested).

Comment: Would have thought there would be a more conventional way but this works for me. Thanks!

Comment: @wtgeographer it may seem this is an obvious feature. However, don't forget this is a client *mapping* framework; while there is nothing stopping it from offering more sophisticated relational data access (and *Mapbox GL* is *already* bursting with [more or less needed] functionality), I would not say that it should necessarily be used that way. Rather, IMO, pre-categorize and encode as much information as possible on the backend (and in DB), and transfer only the bare minimum of data to the client - think perfomance/bandwith, and security (i.e. obfuscating internal data structures).

Comment: Agreed! Thanks @geozelot